# How can I solve this limitation problem by using $\varepsilon$ & delta?

Tags: self-learning, epsilon-delta

the Question is

> $\frac{2n+(-1)^n}{n+1}$ converges to $2$ as $n$ goes infinite

i try to arrange $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ and i managed it to

$\left|\frac{(-1)^n-2}{n+1}\right|<\varepsilon$. but i can't proceed more.

how can i deal with $(-1)^n$??? the answer gives one example of delta, which is $3/\varepsilon$

Comment: Observe that $-3 \ge (-1)^n -2 \le -1$ the $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ is to deal with the $-3$ lower bound.

Comment: Hint: $|(-1)^n-2|$ is one of $3$ and $1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: make your expression simpler using inequalities, in particular the triangle inequality.  $\left\lvert \frac{(-1)^n - 2}{n + 1}\right\rvert \leq \left|\frac{(-1)^n - 2}{n}\right| \leq \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right| + \left|\frac{2}{n}\right|$
Now see if you can demonstrate that the right side of the inequality is smaller than $\epsilon$ for $n > \frac{3}{\epsilon}$